# Flask Python - multiple URL parameter with brackets

Tags: python, flask

hope you are all doing well.

Im working on api project using python and flask.
The question I have to ask is, how can I get the values of multiple query string parameter?

The api client is built in PHP, and when a form is submitted, if some of the parameters are  `multiple` the query string is built like `filter[]=1&filter[]=2&filter[]=3...` and so on.

When I dump flask request, it shows something like `(filter[], 1), (filter[], 2), (filter[], 3)`, it seems ok, but then when I do `request.args.get('filter[]')` it returns only the first item in the args ImmutableDict, `filter[]=1`, and I can't access the other values provided.

Any help regarding this issue would be aprreciated.
Happy programming!

Comment: Can you try this?: `request.args.getlist('filter[]')`

Comment: that made it @mechanical_meat, ty

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: should have read the docs properly before

Comment: @mechanical_meat give an answer to this question, so i can up vote it and close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a MultiDict you can access all values for a given key with:

```
request.args.getlist('filter[]')
```

Documentation: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist

Answer (score 0):

try this `request.args.to_dict(flat=False)` to convert

Comment: this works too, but it returns a list of length 1 even if the paramerter is only present 1 time.